# Implement plugin-in architecture with JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, plugins, express

Below is a simple node.js using express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I want to implement a plugin-in architecture, such as by default there is a folder called `plugins`, and they register by themselve when the node.js startup, I don't need to modify the main `server.js`

an example a `foo` plugin, e.g.

```
PluginManager.register("init, function(app) {
    app.get('/foo', function(req, res){
        res.send('Hello from foo plugin');
    });
});
```

Then in my `server.js`, I would have something like

```
// TODO: Scan all scripts under the folder `plugins`
// TODO: Execute all the `init` hook before the app.listen
app.listen(3000);
```

My problem is my plugin codes are all asynchronous , there is no way to block before the `app.listen()`, do you have any idea for a better plugin-in architecture implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like whatever is loading the plugins would raise a callback like anything else.

```
PluginManager.loadPlugins(function() { app.listen(3000); });
```

This way the app wouldn't start listening until the plugins are all loaded.

Comment: But the problem is my `server.js` and don't know how many plugins I need to init and load, and they can start in particular order.

Comment: I suppose that the PluginManager.register method collects the init functions in an array. Then PluginManager.loadPlugins might call with some async helper library (eg [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/)) all of theese init functions, and after call the app.listen callback - something like this: `async.parallel(initFunctions, callback)`

Comment: In terms of the loading, you could have used promises, and let everything "settle" before continuing. [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1):

You should block. It will only impact the "start time" of the application, not the "run time".

- Use `fs.readdirSync` to get all files in the `plugins` directory
- Write them as modules and `require()` them all (`require` is synchronous)
- Plug them into your `Server`

Comment: Yes, for `init` hook I can block, but in the future I might have other runtime `hook` such as `on_result_ready`, `on_get` etc, are there any recommendation for a `plugin pattern` for JS?

Comment: You can look at how YUI implements plugins http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/plugin/. Objects that can have plugins augment `PluginHost` which has `plug` and `unplug` methods.